# Communicate between Native app and Flutter web app as WebView

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have created a **Flutter Web App** and tried to embed into my **iOS App** as a **WebView**. How to pass data from **Native app** to **Flutter Web App** and exit webView in **Native App** when user click on back button in app bar from **Flutter web app**.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Build Flutter web app
- Embed flutter web app as WebView in Native App (iOS and Android Apps)
- Pass data from Native app to Flutter web app
- Exit Native web app when user click on back button from app bar in Flutter web app

Answer (score 0):

You can't communicate web app from android or ios apps. because you should build a web app that has no relation to other platforms. You should deploy your web part as a separate project with URL and
Use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin for web view. so you can communicate with web view like [this](https://newbedev.com/run-some-javascript-in-flutter-webview)